# Finding the maximum return value of a function and the corresponding input for a given number of inputs

Tags: python, optimization

I have been tasked with finding the max deflection of a beam. I need to return a two element tuple with the maximum deflection of the beam and the point, x, at which it occurs. I have made a function getTotalDeflection which returns the total deflection at any point x under multiple loads. I now need my getMaxDeflection function to run through and find a value for x for which the total deflection is the largest then present this value and x in a 2 element tuple.

```
import scipy.optimize as s

class beam(object):

    def __init__(self, E, I, L):
        self.E = E  
        self.I = I  
        self.L = L  
        self.Loads = (0.0, 0.0)
        self.name = "beam"

    def setLoads(self, Loads):
        self.Loads = Loads

    def beamDeflection(self, Load, x):
        P1, a = Load
        L = self.L
        I = self.I
        E = self.E
        b = (self.L - a)
        if x > a:
            return ((P1*b)/(6*L*I*E)) * ((L/b)*((x-a)**3)-(x**3)+((L**2)-(b**2))*x)
        else:
            return ((P1*b*x)/(6*L*I*E)) * ((L**2)-(x**2)-(b**2))


    def getTotalDeflection(self, x):
        return sum(self.beamDeflection(loadall, x) for loadall in self.Loads)

    def getMaxDeflection(self):
        a = s.brentq(self.getTotalDeflection, 0.0, self.L)
        return a
```

I'm a little stuck since I know to use scipy.optimize but my function returns 0.0.

> > b = beam(8.0E9, 1.333E-4, 5.0)
> >
> > b.setLoads([(900, 3.1), (700, 3.8), (1000, 4.2)])
> >
> > b.getTotalDeflection(x)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks again :)

Comment: So the list you need to examine has the structure `[(deflection1, x1), (deflection2, x2), ...]` ?

Comment: Possibly. That's one way of looking at it, but then the maxDeflection function would have to plug in every possible value of x into getTotalDeflection from 0 to 5 to find the greatest total deflection.

Comment: But there isn't a list made at the moment @timgeb.

Comment: then please be more specific. make a minimum example what you need. all the code you pasted is basically useless for this question.

Comment: Okay. The only functions which matter are getTotalDeflection and getMaxDeflection. getTotalDeflection produces the deflection at the point x on a beam. getMaxDeflection must find the value of x for which getTotal deflection is at its largest.

Comment: It must then produce the value for x and the value of getTotalDeflection at that value for x in a 2 element tuple.

Comment: Okay, what I meant was: In order to make a good minimum example, present a few lines of mockup code which produce the values you want to examine. Then include the information what you want to do with these values. Get rid of any non-general terms like deflection or beam when explaining the problem. It does not matter whether the values represent beam intensities or amounts of bananas. I think I *almost* know what you want, but won't answer until I am sure.

Comment: b = beam(8.0E9, 1.333E-4, 5.0)

b.setLoads([(900, 3.1), (700, 3.8), (1000, 4.2)])

b.getTotalDeflection(1.0)
Out[28]: 0.002266357214303576

b.getTotalDeflection(2.0)
Out[29]: 0.003904432358089522

Comment: These are the values at 1 and 2 out of a range of 0-5. I want to find the input value required to get the largest output.

Comment: Please read this: [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @timgeb. Is this better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**:

```
max((self.getTotalDeflection(x), x) for x in x_vals)
```

**Explanation**:

Set up of the beam:

```
b = beam(8.0E9, 1.333E-4, 5.0)
b.setLoads([(900, 3.1), (700, 3.8), (1000, 4.2)])    
x_vals = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) # mockup values
```

I'm still not sure what values for `x` are acceptable, so let's use the sample values in `x_vals`.

We can generate a list of `(deflection, x)` tuples for every value in `x_vals` like this:

```
def_x_pairs = [(b.getTotalDeflection(x), x) for x in x_vals] # [(0.002266357214303576, 1), (0.003904432358089522, 2), (0.00428594336084021, 3), (0.0028860246311577893, 4), (0.0, 5)]
```

Getting the `tuple` which has the largest first element is simple:

```
max_d = max(def_x_pairs) # (0.00428594336084021, 3)
```

The first element is your maximum total deflection value, the second element the corresponding x value.

Putting everything together for the method:

```
def get_max_deflection(x_vals):
    ''' x_vals: iterable x-values
        returns (max_deflection, x_value) tuple '''
    return max((self.getTotalDeflection(x), x) for x in x_vals)
```

Comment: It should go through all possible values for x_vals to find the absolute maximum, so therefore being more accurate. It should be (0.004342733854787473, 2.7473228262151577) for this example.

Comment: @jajabinks Which is what the method I gave you does. You can pass any iterable of `x_vals` to it.

Comment: So how would I exactly do that? I would like x values from 0-5, 5 being L. Thanks you so much again for your help. It is much appreciated.

Comment: So how would you go about implementing it if you want a step size of up to 7 decimal places? I don't think i'll be able to type all those values in XD.

Comment: @jajabinks That's a separate question and one that is easily googled. Please show some effort.